# addEventListener inheritence in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, events, addeventlistener, event-listener

Ok, I have an extremely simple question that hopefully has an extremely simple answer.

I have a class, `Handler`, which is a base class for many other subclasses. `Handler` needs to add an event listener (`addEventListener`). The event listener will be listening for my class, `GlobalVars`, to say, "Hey! All the global variables have been set! Come and get them!"

However, I do not know where along the inheritance chain the method `addEventListener` is given. I do not want `Handler` to subclass a class with many methods like `Sprite`, because trying to find my custom functions in all those other functions is really ugly.

What class should I extend to inherit `addEventListener`?

Haha, or am I an idiot and have no idea what I'm doing?

Comment: In the adobe documentation, you can actually see where a method or property originates.  TO do so, click on the "show inherited public methods" (if not already shown),  and look in the "Defined by" column.    So if you know `Sprite` has `addEventListener`, look up `Sprite` on the the adobe docs, and find the defined by for the addEventListener method.    In this case, it will tell you `EventDispatcher` is where the method is originally defined.   At the very top of the page of a class on the Adobe docs, you can actually see the inheritance chain as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit from the [`EventDispatcher`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) class.

Answer (score -1):

Inherit using the [EventDispatcher class](http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/actionscript-3-creating-custom-event-handlers-using-eventdispatcher/)

Comment: This adds nothing beyond the answer prior to yours. If you want to add a link to a tutorial, just do so in the comments.